# jquery selector not returning array

Tags: jquery

I thought jquery was returning an array when selecting something. But it does not look like that:

With this html:

```
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
```

And this js:

```
var p = $('p');
console.log(Array.isArray(p)); // result is false
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/413986/) Then the selected paragraphs are not in an array. Why is that?

Comment: What made you think that?

Comment: jQuery doesn't produce arrays, although its behavior relies on iterative programming over an object that represents a collection.

Comment: You can use `var p = $('p').get()` to return the jQuery collection as a standard array of elements. See the documentation: [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: @Kaiido Because you can loop over it as an array, and it has length as an array...

Comment: @EricC so does a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var p = $('p');
```

This code is returning an object, instead of an array. If you want the array result, convert it to array.

```
var x = p.toArray();
console.log(Array.isArray(x)); // result is true
```